# NotFoundHttpException laravel error when i want new route why?

Tags: php, laravel

Why i have **NotFoundHttpException**???

---

My code is working fine, except for this route.
I have another route which looks like this and it's working fine.
I tried to remove (id) and write id in *controller*

```
function npa()
{
    $news = Post::where('category_id', 28)->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(12);
    return view('npa', compact('news'));
}

Route::get('/npa/{id}', 'HomeController@npa');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your id is not optional in the route change your route to this:

```
Route::get('/npa/{id?}', 'HomeController@npa');
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass Id to your route -> Route::get('/npa/{id}', 'HomeController@npa') as /npa/28

And change your function as

```
    function npa($id)
    {
       $news = Post::where('category_id', $id)->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(12);
       return view('npa', compact('news'));
    }
```